# Control the target window of outputfield if a link

Tags: visualforce

Are there any known workarounds for controlling the target window when clicking a link if the link was generated from an outputfield?

I didn't see anything mentioned in the docs on this.. but it would be nice so I don't have to perform extra queries to display the name of an OwnerId for example.

Thanks!

Example:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!t.OwnerId}" target="_parent">{!ownerNameString}</apex:outputLink>
```

Is it possible to specify a target attribute like in the outputLink above, but instead for an outputField when it will be rendered as a link?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more here ?Can you post some code you have used

Comment: @MohithKumar added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with a standard visualforce.
One workaround is to catch the `click` event on all `a` tags that are wrapped with an element with a certain css class and "redirect" the link target to the new window/tab.
For example:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.openInPopup a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });    
</script>

<apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="openInPopup">
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputField value="{!a.CreatedById}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

An easier solution that doesn't involve jQuery is to get the field and just add the target attribute to it. Something along the lines of:

```
<apex:inputField value="{t.owner}" id="ownerId"/>

<script>
  document.getElementById('{!$Component.ownerId}').target = "_blank";
</script>
```