# apex:outputField of a lookup relationship field - is there a way to open in new tab

Tags: visualforce, lookup, outputfield

We are using apex:outputField for some lookup relationship fields and enjoys the benefits of Salesforce supported pop up. But the link will open in the current tab. Is there an easy way to set it opening in a new tab? Without losing the salesforce supported pop up?

Comment: u can get it done with javascript .. something like this one http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30253/control-the-target-window-of-outputfield-if-a-link

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I know... Thank you for that. But poping up all the fields with the information needed is a decent amount of work which means we might don't even want to do that.

Comment: You will *have to* catch somehow clicks on that outputField links to be able to modify the target. No other way to control it with a standard functionality.